# Password entry required for prompts keep appearing in terminal after installing openvpn

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn

I have installed openvpn client in my ubuntu 20.04 machine. I have to connect to an openvpn server with CA password. It keeps on propmpting me for the CA password even if I am not connected to the vpn.

[Here is the screenshot of the issue.](https://i.ibb.co/B401DzZ/openvpn-issue.png)

Things I have tried:

- Tried stopping and disabling the open vpn's systemd service.
  The issue goes away if I uninstall the open vpn package, but I cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is detailed in the post
[Starting openvpn error: "Please enter password with the systemd-tty-ask-password-agent"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765951/starting-openvpn-error-please-enter-password-with-the-systemd-tty-ask-password)
with various proposed solutions.

I repeat here the most upvoted answer
([link](https://askubuntu.com/a/809861/963426)):

> This happens since Ubuntu 15.10 uses systemd to start openvpn.
> Following seems to work me for me. After you start openvpn and get the
> error message from the terminal do the following
>
> ```
> sudo systemd-tty-ask-password-agent
> ```
>
> You will be prompted to enter your username. Now type in the same command again
>
> ```
> sudo systemd-tty-ask-password-agent
> ```
>
> This time you will be prompted to enter your password. After entering the password start the vpn
> connection again. For me I do it with the following command
>
> ```
> sudo service openvpn start
> ```
>
> Now it should connect successfully.

If this answer doesn't work for you, try the other answers in the post.